# How to make an HTML element readonly based on PHP value

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, whitespace

I have this code:

```
<input type = "text" value = "$va" name = "n"/>
```

and I want it to be readonly if va is not whitespace. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This should make it so that if `$va` contains whitespace the field will be readonly.

```
<?php

$readonly = (!empty($va) && strlen(trim($va)) == 0) ? null : 'readonly';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$va.'" name = "n" '.$readonly.' />';
```

However I'm not sure if you also want to include an empty string as "only including whitespace", in which case you could alter the first line to:

```
$readonly = (strlen(trim($va)) == 0) ? null : 'readonly';
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1st Option With Java Script

in javascript you can do it like this:

1st: put an id to your element

```
<input type = "text" value = "$va" name = "n" id='n'/> //i just made it the same as the name
```

2nd: get the element with the id of 'n'

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var nValue = $("#n").val();
    if( nValue != " " ) {
        $("#n").prop("readonly",true);
    }
});
</script>
```

> 2nd Option With PHP

in php, assuming that you are printing your element via php:

```
//other codes here
<?php $va = "noAWhiteSpace"; 
$readOnly = "";
if($va != ""){
    $readOnly = "readonly";
}
?>
<input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $va; ?>" name = "n" <?php echo $readOnly;  ?> />;
```

Comment: You have something screwy going on with your PHP. Check for syntax errors.

Comment: sorry about that, there should be a single qoute `'` at `id="n";` and it should be like this `id="n"';` a single qoute before the semicolon.

Comment: You've got `$va` in single quotes. Also it might not be `" "`. It might be a longer string of spaces, or contain tabs or line breaks, all of which are considered whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

here is

```
<input type = "text" value = "$va" name = "n" <?= ($va != '' || $va == null) ? '' : 'readonly'; ?>/>
```

check https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php